# Django using one time call function output as global value

Tags: python, django, api, server

While initializing the project, i want to call login function from projects settings for once and use the output token anywhere in project. I want to use same token  whether I call again to check if token changed.

```
def login(creds):
    r = requests.post(base_url + '/api/admin/login', json=creds, headers=headers, verify=False)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        token = r.json()['token']
        return token
```

If i call function in project settings, function starts each time. I don't want to dump token to a file and read each time. Any other way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to separate responsibilities for login, authentication and use of token. In practice you'd store token in session. Django provides full support for anonymous sessions, but this could limit your application in cases, when you'd like to store some data associated to that user in the local database.

What I recommend is to setup User model in the local database where you save usernames. Next you create a function for authentication:

```
import requests

def authentication(username, password):
    creds = {'username': username, 'password': password}
    headers = 'whatever'
    r = requests.post(base_url + '/api/admin/login', json=creds, headers=headers, verify=False)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        token = r.json()['token']
        # Create user in the local database if it does not exist yet
        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username)
        return token
    else:
        error = 'Something went wrong'
        return error
```

Next you create login functionality.

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.shortcuts import render

def login(request):

    # Check if user is authenticated by call is_authenticated() and
    # additionally check if token is stored in session
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.session.get('token', False):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_page'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        auth_data = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if auth_data is not None:
            # Save token in session
            request.session['user_token'] = auth_data
            # Get user and login
            # Because you created a user in local database, 
            # you can login that user in this step
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            login(request, user)
            next = request.POST.get('next', '/') if request.POST.get('next') else '/'
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
       else:
            # Implement some error handling here
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

The next logical step would be to control this users tokens somehow. Decorators come to rescue. You create a decorator that checks token. For example something in this sense:

```
import functools
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url
from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login

def token_required(func, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def decorated_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check if token is saved in session
        # Redirect to login page if not
        if not request.session.get('token', False):
            path = request.build_absolute_uri()
            resolved_login_url = resolve_url(login_url or settings.LOGIN_URL)
            # If the login url is the same scheme and net location then just
            # use the path as the "next" url.
            login_scheme, login_netloc = urlparse(resolved_login_url)[:2]
            current_scheme, current_netloc = urlparse(path)[:2]
            if ((not login_scheme or login_scheme == current_scheme) and
                (not login_netloc or login_netloc == current_netloc)):
                path = request.get_full_path()           
            return redirect_to_login(
                path, resolved_login_url, redirect_field_name)
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

You'd need to implement your logic here. This decorator only check if token is stored in session, nothing else. You'd then use this decorator in views as in

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

@token_required
@login_required
def user_logout(request):   
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```